# How to format a result going to JSON from a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In rails, lets say I do this:

```
def retrieveAllWidgets
widgets = Widgets.all(:conditions => "status = 1")

render :json => widgets

end
```

in a rails controller. The json response will contain all the attributes of widget that are exposed. The issue is the widgets have a price, and before sending the JSON response back to the client I want the price to be formatted with number_with_currency.

I think I could do this:

```
def retrieveAllWidgets
widgets = Widgets.all(:conditions => "status = 1")

formattedWidgets = []
widgets.each do |widget|
    formattedWidgets.push({"id" => widget.id,
                          ...
                           "price" => number_to_currency(widget.price)
                          }
                         )
end 

render :json => formattedWidgets

end
```

But is that the way to do it? Is there anyway of appropriately formatting without looping over all results? number_to_currency is really useful, but is I think best used in the view but thats not appropriate for my needs as a JSON response. I could be doing things entirely wrongly. The point is that it's a JSON response only, that is then used in a one page app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you have to format the data in the view, RetrieveAllWidgets.json.erb.
You would have to pass in @widgets. The view will return the json after you format it.
Having a lookig at http://api.rubyonrails.org/ and searching erb may help